# replace url with other url using jquery

Tags: jquery, replace

how can I replace all url's in a page with different URL using jquery ?
thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this:

```
//Create an object of all links
var links = $('a');
//Parse each item in links object
for (var a in links){
//This will allow the for iteration to give the actual link objects that are
//referred to with numeric indexes and not objects that jQuery appends
//Object 'a' should be a number
    if(a == parseInt(a)){
        //Variable b is now the object that is links[a];
        var b = links[a];
        //Variable c is now variable b cast to jQuery so I can use built in jQuery functions
        var c = $(b);
        //Variable temp now contains the href of that link
        var temp = c.attr('href');
        //This should filter out any anchors in the page or any links without an href
        if(temp != undefined){
            //This checks to see if they are inline links, mailto link, OR absolute link
            //This isn't perfect in the case that your link was 'mailsomething.php' or any non http link (ftp or other protocol)
            //The correct scenario here is to use regex but I didn't have the patience
            //or time to do so, so I didn't plus I knew my links didn't apply to these caveats
            var test = temp.substring(0,4);
            if(test != 'mail' && test != 'http' && test != '#'){
                //Now we prepend the abosulte url with the proper and add the relative file location
                c.attr('href','http://differentsubdomain.domain.com/'+temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

on this page:

[Rewrite all links on a page...](http://www.aknosis.com/2009/02/11/using-jquery-to-rewrite-all-relative-urls/)

Comment: If it works, then you should award him the correct answer by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
$("a").attr("href","anotherurl.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

This will select all anchors in the page:
$('a')

This will set the href attribute:
$('a').attr('href','')

I'm not sure what that would be needed for, tho.